# Replace month abbreviation with number

Tags: r

For example: `df$Date`

```
SN              Date
1        07-Mar-2019
2        06-Feb-2019
```

how do I set a condition to replace the value "Mar" = "03" and "Feb" = "02" in df$Date?

So that the output will be:

```
SN         Date
 1   07-03-2019
 2   06-02-2019
```

anyone can help? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as.Date`. You can read about different formats at `?strptime`

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%d-%b-%Y")
df
#  SN       Date
#1  1 2019-03-07
#2  2 2019-02-06
```

Or if you don't want to worry about format use `dmy` from `lubridate`

```
df$Date <- lubridate::dmy(df$Date)
```

Or `anydate` function from `anytime`.

```
df$Date <- anytime::anydate(df$Date)
```

---

To get output exactly in the same format as shown, we can do

```
df$Date <- format(as.Date(df$Date, "%d-%b-%Y"), "%d-%m-%Y")
df
#  SN       Date
#1  1 07-03-2019
#2  2 06-02-2019
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(SN = 1:2, Date = structure(2:1, .Label = c("06-Feb-2019", 
"07-Mar-2019"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thank you. I managed to change the format using Striptime().  But just curious, how about just replacing certain values instead of the date format

Comment: @Thomas You have 12 unique months, date could be from any of the month.  Replacing certain values means you need to add 12 different conditions for each month. It is better to keep dates in Date class so that it is easy to any calculation on them . It is also easy to change the format easily when you have dates in `Date` class. To have similar format as original one, you can do `df$Date <- format(df$Date, "%d-%m-%Y")`. So that you get exact desired output.

Comment: @Thomas I have updated the answer so that you get the same format as in your desired output.